# Releasing ViewControllers form memory inside a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uinavigationcontroller

I'm building an app using a `UINavigationController`. I have a `ViewController` that shows some content, and when it receives interaction from the user (tapping a button for example) a new `ViewController` is displayed.

Here is the code:

**FirstViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)goToSecondVC:(id)sender{  
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: secondVC];    
}
```

I want to release `FirstViewController` from memory once `SecondViewController` has appeared. And then for example, if I jump from `SecondViewController` to `FifthViewController` I'd like `SecondViewController` to be released as well. 
The memory consumed by the app increases when I jump back and forth between controllers, meaning that they are not being released. Any thoughts?

This is what happens with the memory indicator when I switch between controllers. ARC is activated:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`UINavigationController` uses stack data structure to mange `viewControllers`, so you have 2 operations: `Pop` and `Push`. `firstVC` --push-> `secondVC` --push-> `thirdVC`. now first, second and third will stay in memory for faster popping. If you think that this consume a lot of memory than you can use other presentations for your `viewController`, for example modally presenting it, or adding it as a chiled viewController and then remove it manually, but with `UINavigationController`, only pop operation will ensure that the viewController will be released (if no other strong references on it).

Answer (score 0):

No.  You don't want to release these view controllers.  They're part of the navigation stack and remain in memory so they can quickly be navigated back to.  If your app is using too much memory, you need to find other places to consume less memory or you need to use something other than a navigation controller.

Comment: What would you use instead of a `UINavigationController`?

The logic I want to use is the following: 1-I load a VC 2-I jump to another VC and release the first one. 3-If i want to go back to the first VC I create a new instance of it and jump to it.

Comment: Why is it so important that the view controllers be released from memory?  I understand you want to have good performance, but view controllers shouldn't take up a lot of memory, and you probably get better performance overall by not having to instantiate a new instance of a view controller every time you need to present it.

Comment: Each `ViewController` contains a lot of multimedia content that can add up to memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct, you should avoid such logic.

But there is a trick to do such stuff.
You can -setViewControllers on your navigationController and paste there only those vc you want to stay in stack.

For ex. to release FirstViewController, you can call on Second (on viewDidAppear for ex.)

```
NSArray *viewControllers = @[self];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
```

Comment: And now, you're definitely wasting memory because you have a navigation controller that can't navigate.

Comment: Definitely. As I said before - you should avoid such logic.

Comment: Yes, this works if you really need to remove VCs from `navigationController` and free it from memory.. removing the vc using `navigationController?.viewControllers.removeObject(_:)` will create a retain cycle and cause the memory not safely released.

Answer (score 0):

You cann't do this. Because Navigation controller hold all view controller when it is push from it. When you try to pop, it will release it. Before you try to manually release it. It will get crash. If upnormally increase memory during navigation means, use `instrument` and **find out leaks** and fix it.

Comment: There probably aren't any leaks here.  This is completely normal expected UINavigationController behavior here.