# Presenting login page after session is expired

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am developing an app which requires user to SignIn into the app. Suppose user loggedIn into my app and the session is maintained on the server. Due to any network issues or any other reason, the session is expired on the server in future. After that for any server request the server will throw bad request. I am catching this situation and presenting an alert to the user that his session is expired and they need to re-login.Cleared `NSUserDefaults` as well. On click of `Alert OK button`, signIn page is presented to the user.
My question here, is it the right way? From the ViewController documentation, its stated that, `presented ViewController` will be displayed over the `presenting ViewController`. So I want to know that what happened to my previous ViewControllers after presenting the `SignInViewController`, will it leak any memory or give any unexpected behaviour? To clarify question added a flow below. I want to know after the last step, what would happened with ViewControllerB

SignInViewController > ViewControllerA > ViewControllerB >(session expired)> AlertViewController >(presented)SignInViewController

```
- (void)presentLoginScreenAfterSessionIsExpired
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"employeeId"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"userName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"emailId"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"profileImageData"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"role"];

/** showing alert to the User **/
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:
@"Oops!" message:@"Your Session Has Been Expired, Please Re-Login" 
preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:
NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK Action")
style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) 
{ 
 UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

  /** presenting signInViewController **/

    UIViewController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
@"signInViewController"];
 [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}];

[alert addAction:okAction]; // Here action is added to alert controller.
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question; do you need to notify previous view controllers that the session is expired and you need to present the SignInViewController?

Comment: No, I don't want to notify any view. I just want to present SignInViewController. My question is what happened to the view which was already presented. Please check my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're presenting a modal view controller on top of your `ViewControllerB`, the view controller simply will cover the previous view controller. All the view controllers you have currently in your stack will remain in memory. You can also notify your previous view controllers about the success or the failure of the login action with a `protocol` or a `NSNotification`.

SOF has other questions about this topic that can clarify you more the lifecycle of view controllers, e.g. this: [Releasing ViewControllers form memory inside a UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377296/releasing-viewcontrollers-form-memory-inside-a-uinavigationcontroller)

Comment: yeah, that is my concern. there is no point keeping the old viewcontrollers in the memory, cause user ll be forced to SignIn again.